# while attempting to import sklearn in Jupyter notebook and Pycharm, i continuously get error

Tags: scikit-learn

i have installed scikit-learn using pip command, however while trying to import module of sklearn in Jupyter notebook as well as in Pycharm, i continuously get following error. I am working in python3.9.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-355840b7cb6c> in <module>
----> 1 import sklearn.linear_model as lm

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py in <module>
     79     # it and importing it first would fail if the OpenMP dll cannot be found.
     80     from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
---> 81     from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
     82     from .base import clone
     83     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py in <module>
     44     from ._check_build import check_build  # noqa
     45 except ImportError as e:
---> 46     raise_build_error(e)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py in raise_build_error(e)
     29         else:
     30             dir_content.append(filename + '\n')
---> 31     raise ImportError("""%s
     32 ___________________________________________________________________________
     33 Contents of %s:

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/_check_build.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/../.dylibs/libomp.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/../.dylibs/libomp.dylib
___________________________________________________________________________
Contents of /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build:
__init__.py               __pycache__               _check_build.cpython-39-darwin.so
setup.py
___________________________________________________________________________
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.

If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [in this bug report](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/19063), the new sklearn version 0.24 crashes on MacOS<10.15 systems.

Until this bug is fixed, the developers suggest installing the previous version using `pip install -U scikit-learn==0.23`.